# How do I return an object property from a function within a constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

I'm building a small world builder in JavaScript (part of a larger simulation).

**I'm trying to define an object's property in the constructor function by assigning a functions output to it.**

In the code below, *'this.identifier'* executes like a charm, but I want to assign more complex functions to for instance 'this.gender'.

In *'this.gender'* I want to use math.random.math.floor to cycle through an array (that has two values, male and female).

When I write the actual function, *'this.gender'* is dropped from the new Human object.

```
 {
   "identifier":42,
   "lifestate":"Alive",
   "health":"100",
   "age":"10",
   "metabolism":"12",
   "econsumption":"11111",
   "parent":"yes"
}
```

- gender is dropped the moment I change it to a function.

I've tried using a return statement, but it makes no difference.

```
class Bluehuman {
  constructor() {
    this.identifier = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
    this.lifestate = 'Alive';
    this.health = '100';
    this.age = '10';
    this.metabolism = ['Low','Medium','High'];
    this.econsumption = '11111';
    this.parent = ['Yes','No'];
    this.gender = ['Male','Female']; // Want to change this to a function without dropping from the new Bleuhuman object
    }
  }

var bluehuman = {};
var bluehumans = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bluehuman[i] = new Bluehuman();
  bluehumans.push(bluehuman[i]);
}

var arrayPrint = JSON.stringify(bluehumans);
console.log(arrayPrint)
```

**How can I assign the output of a function to 'this.gender' without having it dropped from the new bluehuman object?**

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. You should show the code that *isn't* working.

Comment: JSON cannot contain functions.

Comment: @JonasWilms, it sounds like the OP wants the *result* of a function, like `this.identifier`: `How can I assign the output of a function...`

Comment: Could you please add the code that did not work (with the function) ?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments Jonas and Mark. Really do appreciate. The comment from @DanyalImran below solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function, an expression is just fine to solve your problem

```js
class Bluehuman {
  constructor() {
    this.identifier = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
    this.lifestate = 'Alive';
    this.health = '100';
    this.age = '10';
    this.metabolism = ['Low','Medium','High'];
    this.econsumption = '11111';
    this.parent = ['Yes','No'];
    this.gender = ['Male','Female'][Math.round(Math.random())];
    }
  }

var bluehuman = {};
var bluehumans = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  bluehuman[i] = new Bluehuman();
  bluehumans.push(bluehuman[i]);
}

var arrayPrint = JSON.stringify(bluehumans);
console.log(arrayPrint)
```

Comment: Thank you Danyal. Your solution worked. I'll try it out with this.motabolism and the rest. Really do appreciate :-)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. It this solution worked, mark it as verified so someone in future who might get stuck on this problem will know how resolve it :) @SnoobySchool

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign a function as any other value

```
  this.test = function() { };
```

you will then be able to call it as:

```
  new Bluehuman().test();
```

and if you log it to the console directly, you'll also see it:

```
  console.log(new Bluehuman());
```

If you however call `JSON.stringify` on it, it will be turned into a string containing only data, functions (and a lot of other things) get removed.

Comment: Thank you Jonas. I'll be using your suggestion for the update portion.